# Getting the current layer folder from a recipe

Tags: yocto, recipe

- I have defined a layer for my company applications and all of them uses the same license that is not standard.
- I want to put my license file on a central location (say the layer root directory).

My question is:

How can I get from inside my recipe the layer path? so I can write something like:

```
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${LAYER_ROOT_PATH}/license;md5=ddab9d0ed499556ec3ce30314a81b47a
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do this:

Put your license file, let's call it `customlicense`, in a directory in your layer (e.g. `licenses`), then add that path to the path where licenses are searched, in your `layer.conf` file:

```
LICENSE_PATH += "${LAYERDIR}/licenses"
```

Now you can reference the license inside the `licenses` directory without specifying a path like this:

```
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://customlicense;md5=ddab9d0ed499556ec3ce30314a81b47a"
```

Comment: In case of using this approach, how the `LIC_FILES_CHKSUM` assignment will look like?

Comment: I added it to my answer.

Comment: @LasseMeyer: I did what you suggested, but there is still an error `LIC_FILES_CHKSUM points to an invalid file`. It is trying to find this file in the build directory: `build/tmp-angstrom-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/vmhubd-server/7.2-r0/`

Comment: Try to going through this conversation and try the suggestions: https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2013-June/014314.html

Comment: does not work with yocto 2.7: LIC_FILES_CHKSUM points to an invalid file

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to your layer root using the `${COREBASE}` BB variable which points to the poky layer, but this may be not the best way to deal with the license file issue you mentioned.